# F# NetStandard 2 Sytem.Net.Http name space missing

Tags: dll, f#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard-2.0

I am new to F# and I apologize if this question was asked before, but I could not find it.

I am trying to create an F# DLL in NetStandard 2.0 and I would like to use `HttpClient`

`open System.Net.Http` does not work: `The namespace 'Net' is not defined.`

I looked and could not find any solutions specific to F# and `HttpClient` in the context of NetStandard 2.0

The name space `System.Net.Http` is there on the C# side using in NetStandard 2.0. No problem there.

On F#, intellisense does not show the `.Http` namespace when expanding `System.Net`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

TIA,

David

Answer (score 1):

That namespace is an assembly that is not automatically referenced as part of .NET, so it needs to be referenced for each project that uses it. It's possible that the C# project already had the reference, or your tooling added it automatically when you tried to open the namespace. So you just need to add a reference to the DLL "System.Net.Http" in your F# project.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the package `System.Net.Http` manually and it gives a warning about bringing Net 4.6 and not NetStandard. It is my understanding that NetStandard 2.0 has that reference built in. In any case, adding the package manually does not work in NetStandard 2.0 :(

Comment: Sounds like a tooling issue. Which IDE are you using? Does it support F# with .NET Standard? It's quite likely that VS2017 does not as it still does not support F# .NET Core.

Comment: hello again. Your are correct. It is a VS2017 issue. I tried compiling and running from the CLI and it worked no problem. No extra packages to reference. It worked out the box, like it is supposed to. Thanks...